# Style Counter Or Chapter Counter

Tags: microsoft-word

I am working on a user guide that contains multiple chapters.

We are at point in development where we are inserting additional chapters in the middle of manual. IE, between chapters 2 and 3.

Does MS Word have the option to store the `chapter number` in a variable for a specific style, then when the style is used, it increments the counter? This would only be helpful if it displayed the value of that variable at that point in the document.

I know that word 'knows' how many occurrences of styles, because when you right-click a style is will list the number of occurrences.

This can also have the additional benefit while in development; you can create a chart that would automatically display the number of style occurrences

Comment: Why would you need to count the chapter number style occurrences? The style you assigned to the number is the same that's assigned to the *line* on which the chapter name lies. So if you count the number of occurrences of the *chapter name* (by right-clicking the style assigned to it) it should already give you this information.

Comment: If you insert a new chapter, It would increment the number accordingly.

Comment: if you insert a chapter between 2 & 3, the inserted new chapter automatically will be 3 and 3 will be 4, and so forth

Comment: @TheSavo Dima is right. The new chapter will *automatically* have the number updated. There's no need to have a separate style counter for the number alone.

Comment: I am not using Multi-Level lists

Answer (score 0):

Word 2007 has an inbuilt heading number generator in **Home > Multilevel List**.
[image]

Once you choose your heading style the number gets assigned the *same style* and you can add as many chapters in between 2 and 3 as you want. The numbers will update automatically. Your style counter (right-clicking the style) does the job for *both* the heading number and name.